# Forcing Facebook Like Button to use mobile login page

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to make a Facebook Like button use the mobile version of Facebook's login page, instead of the desktop version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Facebook will detect the browser of user and display appropriate login page.

Currently there is a bug with Login view opened from Like button on mobile: [Clicking Like button within mobile view](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/239652176102303) (which is assigned but not yet fixed). I'm not aware if every mobile client is affected by it.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I always get the non-mobile version?

Comment: Well, it was like this, until the bug (I've updated the answer with details) had place...

Comment: The standard like button doesn't render properly. It draws off the visible display.